# Zend Framework 2 not loading config from mail.local.php

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to get config smtp from mail.local.php, i did tried `ServiceLoader` `getServiceLoader` method, but I am unable to find a way to get configurations in my helper class:

What would be the best way to get `autoload\mail.local.php`,

```
namespace Helpers;

use Zend\Mail;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

class SendEmail
{
    public static function email($to = '', $recipientName = '', $template = '')
    {
        $transport = new SmtpTransport();
//        $options = new SmtpOptions(array(
//            'name' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
//            'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
//            'port' => 2525,
//            'connection_class' => 'crammd5',
//            'connection_config' => array(
//                'username' => 'f11f5a55fdfbf5',
//                'password' => '7780e1e7ee1cc5',
//            ),
//        ));

        $mail = new Mail\Message();
        $html = new \Zend\Mime\Part($template);
        $html->type = 'text/html';
        $body = new \Zend\Mime\Message;
        $body->setParts(array($html));
        $mail->setBody($body);
        $mail->setFrom('admin@fonedoctors.com', 'Admin FoneDoctors');
        $mail->addTo($to, $recipientName);
        $mail->setSubject('Unpaid Invoices');

        $transport->setOptions($options);
        $transport->send($mail);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can render a config file using [Zend\Config\Reader](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.config.reader.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your configuration file in `/autoload/mail.local.php` the configuration will have already been merged together as part of the ZF bootstrapping process. The merged module configuration can then be fetched from the service manager using `$serviceManager->get('config');`

To inject this configuration into your `SendEmail` class, you should ideally create a new factory.

```
class SendEmailFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $config =  $container->get('config'); // all merged module configuration

        $emailOptions = isset($config['my_email_config_key'])
            ? $config['my_email_config_key'] 
            : [];

        return new SendEmail($emailOptions);
    }
}
```

You will also need to register the service with the service manager :

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        SendEmail::class => SendEmailFactory::class,
    ],    
],
```

And update the `SendEmail` class to accept the options via the constructor.

```
class SendEmail
{
    private $options;

    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }
    // ...
}
```